# File recovery due to e2image interrupted resize

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, data-recovery

While resizing a partition inside of gparted live, the kernel hit a GPF, forcing me to reboot the machine. (dmesg here https://pastebin.com/LGqXA3p9). As it so happens, the partition being moved about was on an md RAID5 array and not at all relevant for the system to boot, meaning I am back up and running and able to poke around some more.

Running dumpef2s yields 'dumpe2fs: Corrupt extent header while reading journal super block' and fsck.ext4 says "Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8)". I have not cleared that yet.
testdisk only sees the new partition and none of the files; Photorec would be more hassle than it is worth. Testdisk only shows a half moved file and nothing else.

The last message from the resize2fs tool was "node 279256 / 593596231", which I am not sure how to interpret. Is there a way to tap into the unmoved filesystem data?

Answer (score 1):

After digging around beneath the surface I got lucky - a (proprietary) tool called r-studio found the file system super block - e2image had not yet over ridden the original file system. armed with the sector numbers I was able to simply recreate the old partition to find no data loss at all.
I was in the process of trying to grep my way through the volume looking for the UUID which I still had, which was roughly the same approach but manually done versus the aforementioned tool.
Needless to say I have made e2image backups of the file system meta data and will be investigating why gparted failed.